# Angular 6 creating dynamic components

Tags: angular

I've got an Angular application and I need to create components dynamically without a need to recompile app.

Is there an option that I could make a markup of pre-made components like

```
<app-wrapper>
  <app-article></app-article>
</app-wrapper>
```

Save it in the DB and then insert it in my page so that these components would work?

The idea is to create a kinda constructor so that user could make up own "component" out of other components, save it on the server and then it will be inserted for example via `innerHTML="customComponent"`

Comment: I dont think whatever you are trying is possible. You can create reusable component in angular and do AOT build which will generate compiled code.

Comment: Currently the easiest way is to create angular elements and register them to the browser, then you can use the `innerHtml` https://angular.io/guide/elements#transforming-components-to-custom-elements

Comment: You can also use the old way but it is much more complicated https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 1):

With Angular Elements, the simplest way:

You have to convert the components into custom elements so that the browser knows what they are.

Eg: How to register an Component:

```
import { Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { createCustomElement } from '@angular/elements';
```

You need to declare the injector

```
constructor(private injector: Injector) {}
```

**The 2 lines you are looking for**:

```
const myElement = createCustomElement(ElementComponent, { injector });
customElements.define('app-element', myElement);
```

Then if you inject html via `innerHtml` this element will display properly.

You can learn more about the Angular elements in the [official doc](https://angular.io/guide/elements)

---

The old way, much more complicated is with https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader#dynamic-component-loading

Answer (score 0):

No in angular it is not that simple. You need to do some study to explore how angular creates a component.

https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

This is another great post which I followed for creating the dynamic component
https://netbasal.com/dynamically-creating-components-with-angular-a7346f4a982d

One more interesting things I would like you to explore it Portal of `@angular/cdk` which makes the above steps a bit easier

Comment: Using angular elements it's extremely easy.

Comment: Yes, but there is no point if I want this is in an angular application only.

Comment: @vi What do you mean? The question is about using dynamic component in an Angular app. I just give you a solution.